# Joomla 1.5.26 won't let me insert html

Tags: html, cms, joomla, embed

I am using the following code to try to embed chat in to an article in Joomla 1.5.26:

`<iframe src="http://xxxxxxx.com/welcome/visichat/"
width="100%" height="550px" frameborder="0"
scrolling="no"></iframe>`

Whenever I hit save, the code disappears. Actually, it seems that any html code I try to save disappears. I am trying with the toggle editor tab and the insert html button. Does anyone know why Joomla won't let me embed html?

I am trying to get the chat to load with the site navigation still in place. I'd also be interested in hearing other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: In case what I mention below isn't the issue, what *exact* version are you using? (1.5.what)

Comment: I'm using version 1.5.26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment above, but in v1.5.8 a [content filtering option was added](http://docs.joomla.org/Why_does_some_HTML_get_removed_from_articles_in_version_1.5.8%3F), and turned on by default, that strips HTML unless you say otherwise. It applied to *everyone* no matter what access level, though 1.5.9 then exempted super-admins.

Comment: I followed the link and turned off content filtering, but that didn't change anything. I am using version 1.5.26.

Comment: I played around more with the setting listen in the article and it worked. Thanks.